# Binary Search Tree Construction of height h

Tags: algorithm, performance, tree, binary-search-tree, backtracking

Given the first n natural numbers as the keys for a BST , How can I determine the root node of all possible tree that have a height 'h' .

I already came up with a brute force method where I constructed all possible trees with n nodes and then selected the trees which have a height h but it has a time complexity of nearly O(n!) . Can someone please suggest a better method which would me more efficient ?

Comment: why don't you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891146/count-number-of-binary-search-tree-of-height-h-for-all-possible-roots-over-n-ele/31892691#31892691

Answer (score 1):

**Problem statement.** Given natural numbers `n` and `h`, determine exactly all elements `root` in `1..n` such that `root` is the root of a binary search tree on `1..n` of height `h`.

*Solution*. We can construct a degenerate binary search tree on `1..n` starting from any number in `1..n` by splitting it up at `root`. This changes the lower bounds from the old solution to `h-1`, while the upper bounds remain the same, rendering the full bounds as follows:

```
 h-1 <= max(root-1, n-root) <= 2^h - 1
```

*Old solution (correct only for full binary trees).* [A full binary tree with height `h` has at least `2h+1` nodes, and at most `2^(h+1)-1` nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees). It's easy to see that these bounds are tight, not only for binary trees, but also for binary search trees. In particular, they apply to the `left` and `right` subtrees of your `root`. Since this is a binary search tree on `1..n`, you will have that `left` contains exactly the elements `1..(root-1)`, and `right` contains exactly the elements `(root+1)..n`.

This means that the following is both a necessary and sufficient condition: The *larger* of the subtrees `left` and `right` must satisfy the inequalities

```
2*(h-1) + 1 <= nodes(subtree) <= 2^h - 1
```

In other words, the possible values of `root` are exactly all values in `1..n` satisfying

```
2*(h-1) + 1 <= max(root-1, n-root) <= 2^h - 1
```

**Update.** I blindly looked at an inequality I found at wikipedia without realizing that it only applied to *full* binary trees.

Comment: In the actual problem statement , we need to identify all such trees which have a height less than equal to 'h' and then return the sum of all the root nodes.e.g if n=3 and h=4 , sum=10 . How to achieve this now ?

Comment: If you know how many trees have a particular root, then you can just add them up. This sounds like there might be a closed form formula, but it also sounds like you could do it with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Comment: Can you suggest any formula that could determine how many trees would have a particular root as there is a very tight time limit constraint.e.g if n=3 ,we have 2 trees with root 1 but only 1 tree with root 2

Comment: Try to think of a recursive formula. For example, given `root`, if you can compute the number of binary search trees of height exactly `k` for `k=1..h-1` for both `left` and `right`, then you can compute the number of trees at the given `root`. Once you have your recursive formula, you can convert that into a dynamic programming solution, or use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid computing the same thing twice.

Comment: Wait, are you sure about those bounds? What about a degenerate tree that's just a linked list?

Comment: @templatetypedef *Thanks*, you are absolutely right! I was being lazy and instead of thinking I blindly copied the first inequality I found. The tight lower bound should be `h`.